# How can I see the hidden data of a bootable CD/DVD media?

Tags: filesystems, dvd, el-torito, iso-9660

I have this bootable DVD that holds a recovery program. When I insert the disc in Windows I can only read the label of the disc. When I try to explore the contents I don't see anything. But when I boot from it I get to the recovery program. So, evidently, it can't be just empty!

So how can I see this hidden disc data structure and all of the files in Windows?

**Update:**

Viewing the properties of the disc, under the General tab, it shows 4.38 GB used space, and 0 byte free space. How can this be?

[image: disc properties]

I installed IsoBuster (3.2) as suggested and it shows 127.47 MB used for the whole session. There is one session and one track that includes following three folders.

ACRONIS_MEDIA
Bootable Disc
Acronis Media

The ACRONIS_MEDIA and Acronis Media show up empty, but the Bootable Disc contains BootImage.img and BootCatalog.cat and they are 2kB each.

Screen 1:

[image: screen1]

Screen 2:

[image: screen2]

What kind of file system is used here?...

Why is the IMG file so small and why are there no other files?

Is IsoBuster able to read El Torito? If so, where is the El Torito part? I see ISO and what appears to be a Joliet folder (which is empty and the only one that appears in Explorer in Windows).

Comment: Depends - what kind of environment does it boot into?  The recovery program could be in a compressed image file of some sort, so you may not be able to access the files unless you can open the image.  Also, if you examine the disk in Disk Management, are there any partitions that are not mounted?  It may be using a file system that is not Windows readable.  Or, as @Ramhound mentioned, it may just have hidden files . . .

Comment: I'm not sure what they call it, but it's a bootable media from Acronis, the company that makes True Image. I think it's Linux based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the recovery program is completely contained in the [El Torito Boot Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29), which Windows doesn't normally mount for browsing.  A CD recovery program like [IsoBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/help/bootable_cd/dvd) is one way to browse the contents of that portion of the disc.  Another possibility is extracting the boot image and then mounting the disc image with something like [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk).

Comment: I installed IsoBuster, but I only see 2 files and they are 4 kB put together, while the total space used appears to be 127 MB. There is a BootImage.img if that tells you something?...

Comment: You have basically answered my question but I would like to see more. It can't be just two files. Where is the rest of it stored?

Comment: If I want to extract it, do I select the Track 01 and then go to File, Track 01, Extract Track 01, Extract User Data? Or do I only select the BootImage.img?

Comment: If you want to extract it, you'll need the user data for the entire track.  I'm not sure what you're expecting to find once you do though -- you're getting into a mixture of both Linux and El Torito voodoo at this point and everything is going to be Windows-hostile.  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Voodoo?! Lol! I was hoping to find out what version this is and what tools are included in this image. Sometimes there are only tools for restoring backup images in these Acronis bootables, but I will need the disk tools as well before doing a restore. I will try to find a different bootable ISO image from Acronis.

Comment: IsoBuster has already been pretty useful for answering the related question [dvd burning - Real blank DVD+R writable space](http://superuser.com/questions/619650/real-blank-dvdr-writable-space).